# how to do isomorphic ideal from root system of degree 5 or more

Tags: polynomials, ideals, maple

**update1**
i notice solving 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5 have 5 solutions two conjugate real number and each of them having conjugate complex number part

i change

a*b + c

to

a1*a2*b1*b2 + c1*c2**

still can not solve non-isomorphic problem in degree 5 or more

is it the same problem meet by lagrange

**old question**
when design system of polynomials of degree 5, after solve it, it return two or more set of roots

how to do isomorphic ideal from root system of degree 5 or more

solve({f1=s,f2=s,f3=s})
{[a=1,b=2,c=s] , [a=3,b=4,c=s]} 
there are two possible set of roots

first set is a=1, b=2,c=s
second set is a=3, b=4,c=s

which method can ensure only one set of root of system of polynomials when design?

Comment: What do you mean by "set of roots"?

Comment: [a=1,b=2] , [a=3,b=4] there are two possible set of roots

Comment: Roots over the complex numbers or the reals?

Comment: i use reals, actually in my program it return integer and one variable root

Comment: Also, @hilbert, it is considered perfectly acceptable to use complete sentences on math.SE.

Comment: after read myself again, i feel that easy to understand. i will use complete sentence next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you want to design a system of three polynomials $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ in three variables $x,y,z$ with only one real solution: for convenience take that solution to be $x=0, y=0, z=0$.    The zeros of each polynomial will in general form a variety $Z(P_i)$, typically a surface, in $\mathbb R^3$, and you want $(0,0,0)$ to be the only point where all three varieties intersect.  There's lots of freedom to choose the polynomials, as long as you keep that in mind.   If the 
varieties for the first two polynomials are surfaces, they will typically
intersect on a curve.  You then just have to make sure the third variety doesn't intersect that curve except at $(0,0,0)$.

One way that will work
is to make $$P_3(x,y,z) = f(x,y,z) P_1(x,y,z) + g(x,y,z) P_2(x,y,z) + x^2 + y^2 + z^2$$ 
for some polynomials $f$ and $g$.

Comment: what are f and g ?

Comment: Arbitrary polynomials.

Comment: do the terms of f come from P2 ? do the terms of g come from P1 ? any properties or polynomial template can guess f and g?

Comment: Arbitrary means they could be anything you want.

Comment: i made clear for my question, how to do isomorphic ideal from root system of degree 5 or more